# How to maximize a flow in a network without knowing direction of data transferring from a node

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming, network-flow

[image: network of computers]

Suppose we have a network (shown in the image above), and the maximum transfer rate between two computers is written on each link. We want to maximize the transfer rate from computer $o$ to computer $n$ and we have to satisfy these conditions:

1. No link is allowed to proceed its maximum capacity.
2. Each link can transfer data in either direction but not at the same time.
3. We can't save or waste flow in any node, in other words whatever enters each node has to leave.

What I am really stuck on right now is how can I write the 3rd condition in my linear program, could someone please help me, because we don't know the direction beforehand.

Comment: What variables have you defined so far? And how do the  first and 2nd condition Look like?

Comment: Assuming the flows into or out of node $a$ are $v_1, v_2, v_3$, if you wrote $\sum_{i=1}^{3}x = 0$ would mean that the inflow equals outflow. You repeat that for each node except $o, n$, the origin and destination nodes. This is similar to Kirchoff's current law in electric circuits. You can then add sum of outflows from origin must equal sum of inflows into destination (assuming there is no concurrrent flows between origin and destination). If this condition is not true, ie., both $o, n$ can simultaneously trasmit and receive, then treat them like any other node (sum of inflow=sum of outflow)

Comment: @callculus42 your answer made me a bit confused you first defined $v$ but then put sum of $x$ to equal zero but what I did is that I defined a flow for each link and assumed if it flows rightward its positive and if it flow downward like ab then its negative. lets say for example $xbe$ is a flow in link be and is somehow between -3 and 3 and for every link I have written the inequalities. but my point is when I don't know in the final answer the direction of each link how can I write the 3rd condition?

Comment: @nima It seems that yoa addressed your comment to the wrong person.

Comment: @nima You just assume a direction when setting up the equations, it doesn't matter. When you end up solving it, if the flow is the other direction, it will come out as a negative sign in the answer.

Comment: @Merosity are you basically telling that if I put the algebraic sum of the link related to every nodes equal to zero then  the problem is solved? because the book's author hasn't done this so far and have used other method that really confuses me and that is the reason I got very confused solving this problem.

Comment: @nima Yes, that's what it means. For example, for the node $a$, you define the flow from $o$ to $a$, let's say, as $v_1$; the flow from $a$ to $b$ as $v_2$ and the flow from $a$ to $d$ as $v_3$. Then, by the very definition of the variables $v_i$, you have $v_1 = v_2 + v_3$ for your point 3. When solving your problem, if the value obtained for $v_2$ happens to be negative, it means that the flow actually goes from $b$ to $a$.

Answer (score 0):

> 3. We can't save or waste flow in any node, in other words whatever enters each node has to leave.

What this is equating to is that when we use an edge of a node to transfer data into it, we have to use at least one outgoing edge from that node.

A partial model to the problem:

Let $N_{out, in}$ represent the nodes in the network with $out$ being an index that tells us the outgoing node, and $in$ being the index denoting the incoming node that node $out$ is going towards with $out\in\{a,b,c,d,e,o\}$ and $in\in\{a,b,c,d,e,n\}$.

Next, lets have $C_{out,in}$ denote the weight of the edge that connects the two nodes together.

Since we can only use one edge at a time, $N$ is binary for all edges. Thus, we can represent this with a model as the following:

$$\text{Maximize } z = \sum_{out}\sum_{in}C_{out,in}\cdot N_{out,in}$$

Subject to:

$$N_{oa} + N_{ob} + N_{oc} = 1$$

$$\sum_{in}N_{out,in}\le 1 \text{$\quad$} \forall out$$

$$\sum_{out}N_{out,in}\le 1 \text{$\quad$} \forall in$$

$$N_{dn} + N_{en} = 1 $$

$$N_{out, in}\in\{0,1\}\text{ }\forall out,in$$

Lastly, we’ll need a modified [Miller-Tucker-Zemlin constraint](https://phabi.ch/2021/09/19/tsp-subtour-elimination-by-miller-tucker-zemlin-constraint/) to eliminate sub-tours, but we’ll leave that as an exercise for the reader, as the explanation and partial model is enough to answer the question presented. One thing to notice is that this networking problem is a variation of the [Traveling Salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Here’s a [PowerPoint presentation](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Emlavrov/slides/482-spring-2020/slides35.pdf) that gives additional detail on sub-tour elimination of the TSP.